# Songs stuck in Automatically Add To itunes folder

Tags: itunes

I use an mp3 tagger to fix my mp3 tags, and the tagger is set to move my tagged mp3s to the Automatically Add to iTunes folder.  Then, iTunes *usually* copies the tracks to iTunes and organizes the folders accordingly.  For some reason, its not working on three albums.  I can't see anything unique about these albums, but iTunes is adding it to my library, and leaving it in the folder.  Then it seems to repeat this process every so often until I have a number of duplicate entries of the same song, all pointing to the same location.  I've got it working properly before and after adding these tracks, just not for these specific 3 albums.  Any thoughts?

I will post a screenshot as soon as my reputation allows ;)

Answer (score 2):

iTunes will put any songs that aren't compatible into a Not Added folder (underneath Automatically Add).  If your music wasn't compatible then you would find them in the Not Added folder.  So it seems that they are compatible, just not getting deleted.

I would check the permissions on these files and see if iTunes has permission to delete them.  Command-i on the files and folder concerned and ensure your use can read and write them.

Another solution is to open the Console.app application (found in the utility folder in Applications) and observe the output of that whilst iTunes is adding the music and see if there are any specific error messages that may point to why it isn't deleting the files.

Comment: I changed the permissions to Read & Write for everything, and watched the console, but nothing happened. I tried to convert the MP3's to MP3's with iTunes but it gave me an error saying the files are write protected or of the wrong type.  The files seem fine. I'm just going to start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just needed to launch iTunes and it started working for me.

Comment: This answer is "OK", but you could improve it by adding which program you were using to do the same action as the poster. He hasn't specified which app he uses either. Have a peruse around AskDifferent and see what kinds of answers will get up voted or you might find that people will continue to down vote you. It's unfortunate that unless you have a higher score, you can't post requests for more info as a comment. So just make sure you give a bit more "beef" to your answers for the time being. Good luck!